# QWidget background transparent

Tags: c++, qwidget, qt5.6

I have a widget in the main window, the widget has the following styles:

```
    background-color:#ffeeeeee;width:100%;height:100%;
```

It is set-up to widget layout and controls auto size to fill the geometry of the widget, but the background of the widget is always transparent.  What can I do to make it opaque?

This is using Qt5.6 running on RedHat Linux 7.2

NOTE:  The syntax #ffeeeeee is specific to Qt, where the first node is the alpha, then red, green and blue octets.

Comment: Have you tried `setAutoFillBackground(true)`?  I think it's false by default so the background won't be drawn before the `paintEvent` member is invoked.

Comment: Yes, no difference, I also added a call to update but its still transparent.

Comment: Is it opaque when you write `background-color: gray;`?

Comment: Regardless of the style sheet setting, the background is always transparent.

Comment: Please write how do you set the style.

Comment: In QtCreator, select the background of the widget, right click and select "Change stylesheet..." then type in the style sheet as above, I've also tried "background-color: white;"  background is always transparent.

Comment: Is it transparent only in QtDesigner or it is in running program too? And... what is transparency in your case, how do you see it?

Comment: Its actually the other way around, its only transparent when running but opaque in the designer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the background-color present and set to any of the following:

```
    background-color:white;width:100%;height:100%;
```

or

```
    background-color:#ffffff;width:100%;height:100%;
```

or my original:

```
    background-color:#ffeeeeee;width:100%;height:100%;
```

The property, autoFillBackground is set to false and the background of the widget is transparent at run-time.

However removing any background-color style and leaving the style as just:

```
    width:100%;height:100%
```

The property, autoFillBackground is set to true and the widget is opaque.

As far as I can see there is no error in the styles, I believe this may be an error in Qt.

Comment: Are you saying that a call to `setAutoFillBackground(true)` fails if the `background-color` property is set in the style?

Comment: If I add a style for the background-color it automatically changes the value of the autofillbackground node to false.

Comment: Sorry but that's not what I'm asking.  My question is... if I set the style to one that sets the `background-color` property, does a subsequent call to `setAutoFillBackground(true)` not set the `autoFillBackground` to true?  That was the suggestion in my original comment.

Comment: I've tried that and it doesn't work either, and when set to true it wouldn't use the colour set by the style which is what I was getting as as when specifying a colour in style it automatically disables the setting in XML.

Answer (score 1):

You have too many characters in your color. Change:

```
background-color: #ffeeeeee;
```

to:

```
background-color: #eeeeee;
```

If you want to use transparency, you'll have to be explicit:

```
background-color: rgba(...);
```

Comment: No, my post is correct...in Qt the colour for style sheets is formatted as follows, the first node is the alpha, then red, green, blue.  In my example #ff is full opaque.

Comment: sorry it doesn't help.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using QWidget::setWindowOpacity(1) where 1 = opaque and 0 = transperant.

Also try QGraphicsOpacityEffect.The following is code for setting the 50 percent opacity for a pushbutton but It can be extended to a widget as well.

```
ui->setupUi(this);
QGraphicsOpacityEffect * effect = new QGraphicsOpacityEffect(ui->pushButton);
effect->setOpacity(0.5); 
ui->pushButton->setGraphicsEffect(effect);
```

Comment: Yes, and the setting in the XML was 1.

Answer (score 0):

Even though this question is very old, I still stumbled upon this thread while having the same problem and I was out of luck with the "setAutoFillBackground(true)" approach.
Sometimes, you just want a distinct, opaque background for diagnosing sizing and placement issues of a QWidget. What worked best for me, was to override `virtual void paintEvent(QPaintEvent*);`  and implement it as follows:

```
void MyWidget::paintEvent(QPaintEvent* e)
{
  QPainter p(this);
  p.fillRect(rect(), palette().background());
  QWidget::paintEvent(e);
}
```

Replace `palette().background()` by e.g. `QBrush(QColor(255, 255, 0))` for a yellow background.